# glfwSwapBuffers really slow (no vysnc)

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, buffer, glfw

I made a basic opengl program and opened it up and I was only getting 2400fps with dips to 700fps in release mode, and I was really confused so I took out everything in the main loop till the code looks like below

```
while (true)
{
     glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
}
```

and now I'm only getting 3400-4000fps (I switched to release mode).

For a bit of context, I've made a game in DirectX 11 where when nothing is drawing it gets 8000fps and that's with input and game logic not an empty loop.

I've tried compiling my own glfw and using precompiled binaries. Im thinking that maybe I need to figure out how to build glfw as apart of my project so I can get more optimization.

I'm really confused, I want to do some heavy stuff in this game but i'm already getting 2-4x less performance when nothing is going on.

Last second addition:
People have talked about glfwswapbuffers having low performance on other threads but in all those cases they are using vysnc. (im using glfwSwapInterval(0))

Comment: Frame timing should be measured in seconds (or miliseconds), not FPS. Using FPS gives you a poor understanding of frame time. For example, the difference between 2400fps and 8000fps is... 291 *micro* seconds. Not a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a multiple reasons to impact the performance of `glfwSwapBuffers`. Since it works asynchronously, performance might be reduced by synchronizations as `v-sync`, or monitor refresh rate (60Hz?). Usually you want your engine to be in sync with other processes (even if they are a limiting factor). You might also want to try `glfwSwapInterval(0)`.

Comment: The question states that op is already using `glfwSwapInterval(0)`.